# iterating same number using while loop

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn while loops.

I'm trying to iterate same number 10 times using a while loop.

I figured out how I can utilize while loop in order to stop at a certain point as it increases

But I can't figure out how to stop at a certain point without having to add 1 and setting a limit.

Here is my code

```
i = 1
total = 0
while i < 11:
    print i
    i += 1
    total = i + total
print total
```

This prints

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,65

in a separate line

How could I modify this result?

> 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just print a literal `1` and add `1` to the total:

```
while i < 11:
    print 1
    i += 1
    total += 1
```

You need to keep track of how many times your loop is run, and using `i` for that is fine, but that does mean you need to increment it on each run through.

If, during each loop, you only want to *add* one to the total, just do that and don't use the loop counter for that.

Comment: That'll still print 65 instead of 10 at the end . . .

Comment: Ah, I see. This did the job. I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1
total = 0
res = []
while i < 11:
    res.append(1)
    i += 1
print ', '.join(res) +', '+ str(sum(res))
```

or with for:

```
vals = [1 for _ in range(10)]
print ', '.join(vals) +', '+ str(sum(vals))
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a while loop is to keep looping while a certain condition is true.  It seems that you want to perform an action n times then display the number of times the action was performed.  As Martijn mentioned, you can do this by printing the literal.  In a more general sense, you may want to think of keeping your counter separate from your variable, e.g.:

```
count = 1
number = 3
while count <11:
  print number*count
print "While loop ran {0} times".format(count)
```